# Best way to store and refrence lots data in Swift for use in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class, uitableview

This is a bit confusing so I apologise. But:
I am trying to make an app where the user has the ability to add items to a list of individual items that will be displayed back to them(Something along the lines of a todo list app) as a table view.

However, I have hit a roadblock I need to store several different bits of data for each item(Some Strings, Some ints and a date) in the list.

I think that a class(or struct) would be the best way to do this where an instance of the class holds the information need for each item and then the name of that instance is stored in a list so it can be accessed via the indexPath in the table view.

However, I don't know how I am going to make a new instance of the class for every item because the app could have hundreds of individual items.

I'm sorry, this is so confusing and any help would be appreciated! Feel free to ask for more info

Edit: what I am looking for and I'm sure there's a stupidly easy way of doing it but I'm try to work out how to create an instance of a class when the name of the class is stored in a variable. Ecencialy I want the instance of the class to store the item. To be created when the user inputs the item to be added to the table.

Eg. They enter an item. item1 and the other data that goes along with then I want to be able to store that in instance of the item class but I don't know how to make the name of that instance because the name I want which is item 1 is stored in a variable.

Sorry that's so confusing that's the reason I need help

Comment: Hi! Rotely creating hundreds or thousands of instances in the blink of an eye is pretty much the one thing a modern computer is really good at. And under normal circumstances no iOS device would have any problem holding very large numbers of data models in memory for displaying them in a table. So what exactly is your problem/question? Is it how to create objects or structs out of user entered data? How to iterate over large collections of items? How to store object data persistently, and later read it again (e.g. after restarting the app)? How to populate your table from objects you stored?

Comment: Generally, based on your description of your app idea, I recommend checking out [this nice tutorial by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1). It seems they build something very similar to what you want to achieve: the user can enter complex data, which is stored by the app and displayed in a table.

Comment: I would suggest you look at Core Data; it is the in-built object persistence system available in iOS; The Apple tutorial is nice as far as learning about TableViews but they are persisting to a plist, which probably isn't the best approach; I just think they wanted to keep their tutorial simple since Core Data also has a bit of a learning curve.  You can even use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to partially automate your table linkage to the core data store

Comment: I refrased what I said

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't get the relation between an object instance and it's "name" in your rephrased question. Why do you need to store "names" separately, instead of directly storing whole objects with all their data once they have been created?

Comment: Say, for example, your app allows users to add movie ratings. A user enters a movie title, genre and star rating. You create a `MovieRating(title: String, genre: String, rating: Double)` instance from that input with something like `let movieRating = MovieRating(...` , and then append that instance to an array. That array also feeds your `UITableViewDataSource`, so that the user can see all the ratings they entered. What else is missing?

Comment: Yeah I get that my issue is I want to store more than one movie rating and I don't know how to make each new name for the moive rating eg movierating1, movierating2 other than pre define them which I don't want to do because then it limits me to a set number. Thanks so.much for your help

Comment: Oooh, you mean "name" as in "variable name"? Like, the `foo` when you type `let foo = 123`? Yeah, no, they are not what you want to store in a dynamic collection like the one you probably have in mind. If that's what you were trying to do, I recommend to take one step back and look again into [Swift collection types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html), in particular typed arrays, and consider what it means to append or insert object instances into an array, and then how to look up those instances in the array using subscripts, filters, enumeration and so on.

Comment: Thanks heaps I probably could have worded the question better. I'll try figure it out.

Comment: You can use NSCoding here is complete tutorial from Apple. 

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html

Comment: Thanks do you mean for the storage In app sessions or across app sessions coz I did look into the latter and I'm not quite at that stage yet but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first: You can't store the Name of a Class in a Variable and use this variable to get a new instance of a class.

What you need is an Array containing all the different Items. This array is unlimited so you can store as many items in it as you like and you don't need to set a name for each of these Instances.

> First create an empty array containing all `Items` as a property:

```swift
var items : [Item] = []
```

> Second call the function `populateItemArray()` in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```swift
private func populateItemArray() {
    // Populate the items Array (Are you using CoreData, Realm, ...?)
}
```

> Third, use the Item Array to populate the TableView.
>   **REMEMBER: If your only using one section in your tableView, `indexPath.row` is always equal to the corresponding item in the array.
>   E.G. `items[indexPath.row]`**

Hope this helps you!

**UPDATE:**

> Look at this example struct `Item`. As you can see you can also store a date in it:

```swift
struct Item {

    // First create all the properties for your struct.
    var data1: String
    var data2: Int
    var data3: String

    // You can create properties of any type you want, also of type date.
    var dateOfCreation : Date



    // Then implement all the methods of your custom Struct Item.
    func setDate(with date : Date) {
        self.dateOfCreation = date
    }

    func returnDate() -> Date {
        return self.dateOfCreation
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to store a date which you can only do through a struct or class I believe correct me if I'm wrong it's my fault for making a dumb question I tried top rephrase it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707272/how-to-name-an-instance-of-a-struct-the-contents-of-a-variable-swift but I don't think it helps thanks so much anyway.

Comment: @Jaxsonpd First there are no dump questions, so feel free to use this platform to get better and better. Second, you are creating an array of type [Item], this means you can store unlimited Item Objects (of a struct or a class) in this array and each of this Item Object can contain a property of type date

Comment: @Jaxsonpd I Updated my answer above. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: Thanks man what I was looking for was that var items : [item]()

Comment: @Jaxsonpd Happy to hear this, feel free to mark this answer as the solution to close this question.