# How to name an instance of a struct the contents of a variable - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, tableview

There is almost certainly a better way of doing this and I'd love to know but I can't phrase it in a question so essentially here is my problem:

I am creating an app that presents a list of items(In a table view) which have various bits of data that come along with the item(String Int Date ect). I've decided that the best way to store this data is in a struct because it allows me to store lost of different types of data as well as run processes on it.

The problem is that I want to have theoretically an infinite number of items in the list and so I need to make lost of instances of the `Item` struct without predetermining the names of each instance.

I would then store these instance names in an array so that they can be listed in the table view.

I'm completely stuck at this point I've spent hours looking and I just can't make sense of it I'm sure its stupidly easy because hundreds of apps must need to do this. I'm Open to anything thanks.

Currently, I have a struct:

```
struct Item() {
    var data1: String
    var data2: String // (But Should be Int)
    var data3: String

    func setDate() {
        // code
    }

    func returnDate() {
        // code
    }
}
```

and then in the view controller I have:

```
@IBAction func SubmitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var textField1 = Item(data1: textField1.text!, data2: textFeild2.text!, data3: "Units")
    print(textField1.data1)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without predetermining the names of each instance"? It would help clarify your question if you added some code examples of the data/structure you have and what you hope to achieve (even if it's fake - i.e. doesn't compile)

Comment: Ill add it now thank heaps

Comment: If i am understanding this correct, you want to add an item that may or may not contain the name like lazy load..
/

Comment: what its a todo list app kinda if your asking

Comment: O right yeah kinda I think

Comment: You would typically have an array of your `Item` instances.  You don't hold each instance in a named variable.  If you need to store this data between executions of your app, look at Core Data

Comment: I don't quite get what your problem is. You know what an array is, don't you?

Comment: Yeah lol but I have to store a date which gets complicated quickly if you don't store it in a struct or class as I need to do some processing on the date That's what I thought at least might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what your goal is but I guess the final goal is to have an **array of your Item Objects**, which then can be used to populate an `UITableView`??? Without setting up a name for this Instances?

The most easiest solution would be to create a **array** as a `Class Property` for storing all the Items which is empty like this:

```swift
var items : [Item] = []
```

And then in `viewDidLoad()`, you can call a function which populates the item array with all the available Items. 
This Item Array can then be used to populate the **UITableView**.

**Second Part:**
You got this IBAction which creates a new Item. I guess this is supposed to add a new Item to the existing ones.

You can add this new Item to the existing Item Array by using

```swift
items.append(Item(<parameters>))
```

And don't forget to reload the UITableView to include the new data.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thanks, man I think this may have solved it Ill have a crack and get back to you

Comment: @Jaxsonpd Happy t hear this;)